# Jquery .one complet callback

Tags: jquery, callback

I have a jQuery function one for lot of `.class` objects, and I want to call a function complete after .one function was called on all `.class` objects.

This is `.one` function

```
$(".pas_img").one("load",function()
{
   //some code here
}).each(function() 
{
   if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

---

#### EDIT:

OK, I am using a function from [jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached) (the answered solution) for lot of images and dynamically resize them when the image is cached by the browser, and I need to call function when all images are cached so when function `.one("load")` was called to all objects.

Comment: It's confusing to me, please describe your scenario instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 (function () {
     var totImgs = $('.pas_img').length;
     $(".pas_img").one("load", function () {
         if (!--totImgs) {
             alert('all images loaded');
         }
     }).each(function () {
         if (this.complete) $(this).load();
     });
 }());
```